# Unable to write files in Android P

Tags: android, android-file, android-external-storage, android-storage

I couldn’t write files in Android P Memory Card. The same code is working fine in Android O.

```
new File(file.getParent()).mkdirs();
output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
output.writeObject(obj);
```

I am able to read the files from the same device(Memory Card), but when I try to write the file, it is throwing **Permission Denied** exception.

Initially it was throwing me **No such file or Directory**, but after giving root permissions, it is throwing Permission Deniod exception.

Note: My app is **system privileged** app and also I have given the Devicewith root permission by adb root, checked the permissions in Android Manifest file, they look fine.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178378/discussion-on-question-by-perseus-unable-to-write-files-in-android-p).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used DocumentContract and DocumentFile to create files and folders using URI.