# File Not Created in Android P

Tags: android, android-file, android-9.0-pie

I am creating `File`. Its working in all versions except Pie Version. This is my code.

```
private void writeToFile(String data, Context context) {
    try {
         File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "testApp.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.append(data);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922592/unable-to-write-files-in-android-p